# Kotlin Error: "Unresolved reference: nightMode" in my MainActivity.kt file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-night-mode

I have created a To-Do List App in Android Studio using Kotlin and wish to add an options menu item that toggles between regular theme and night mode theme. I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-drawables-styles-and-themes#5)

I have entered everything into my existing app but get the error "Unresolved reference: night mode" in my MainActivty.kt file. I am also getting errors "Expecting an element" and "Expecting an expression". My version of Android Studio is 4.2.1. I am attaching the code from the MainActivity.kt, main_menu.xml, and strings.xml.

MainActivity.kt

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        intent nightMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()
        if (nightMode == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
            menu?.findItem(R.id.night_mode)?.setTitle(R.string.day_mode)
        } else{
            menu?.findItem(R.id.night_mode)?.setTitle(R.string.night_mode)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId ==R.id.night_mode){
            intent nightMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()
            if (nightMode == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
        }
        recreate()
            return true
    }
```

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/night_mode"
        android:title="@string/night_mode>"/>

</menu>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">To do List</string>
    <string name="night_mode">Night Mode</string>
    <string name="day_mode">Day Mode</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

`intent nightMode` is not a valid expression.

The original tutorial Java code seems to have `int nightMode` there, declaring a variable of type `int` (as in integer).

In kotlin you can declare a variable with `val` (immutable) or `var` (mutable).

So, change the `intent` to `val`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. My Menu is now showing options for Night Mode and Day Mode however it only changes the outside of the app and the toolbar to Night mode but not the activity. And when I click on Day Mode the app shuts down! Are you able to look at my code I attached in my question to see what I may have missed. I have followed the tutorial to the letter. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to help me with my other questions I posted? I am stuck and no one has answered me?